# How can get Final Price, with applied price rule in Magento

Tags: magento, discount

For  example

```
$_producte = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2974);
echo $_producte->getFinalPrice();
```

I can get in frontend when insert to .phtml

BUT I can not get  final price (with discount) in admin section or in custom product export file.

Answer (score 12):

Price calculation in Magento is a hot mess. You need to load the frontend event area in order to trigger rule calculation (ref `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice()` configured in `Mage_CatalogRule` *config.xml*).

```
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND,Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);
```

Comment: What about processAdminFinalPrice?

Comment: What about it? Sounds like a new question to me :-) - perhaps here or over at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, that's true but I was surprised why rule calculation triggered by processFrontFinalPrice, Can't it be possible with processAdminFinalPrice? Can ask in separate question.. :)

Comment: FWIW I've learned to be surprised by *nothing* when it comes to Magento price/totals calculation, unfortunately...

Answer (score 3):

I think its not necessary to load the frontend event area part. Often the product is not instanced correctly.

Try:

```
$product
    ->setStoreId(1) //your store_id here
    ->setCustomerGroupId(1) //your favorite customer group id here
    ->load($productId)
```

and then:

```
$product->getFinalPrice()
```

should give the correct final price.

Otherwise try the solutions given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096072/2787671