# Magento in wordpress: [mage object] catalog price rules not applied in externally loaded shopping cart

Tags: wordpress, magento, magento-rules

I am loading the Magento shopping cart block in wordpress with the Mage Enabler plugin, but unfortunately I can't get the catalog pricerules to work with the shopping cart.

When I add a product on which discount is applied through a price rule, the original price is used in the cart, after I add the product to this cart.
The catalog pricerule is working of course because I can see the right price in the product detail page.

### I am using this code:

```
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$cart = $layout->createBlock('Checkout/Cart');
$cart->setTemplate('checkout/cart.phtml');
$cart_content = $cart->toHTML();
echo $cart_content;
```

---

Is there something else I need to do to get the catalog price rules to work in the shoppingcart and checkout, with the Mage Enabler plugin?
So basically I would like to know how to run the catalog pricerules through the Mage:: object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to trigger events. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9685400/833795